# topology-locally compactness

Tags: general-topology

It is a known fact that real numbers are locally compact and rationals are not with respect to the topology inherited from R.

What about irrationals?are they locally compact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the irrationals are not locally compact. What can you say about compact sets in the topology on the irrationals? What would happen if such a compact set contained an open neighborhood of a point? (Note that the irrationals are Hausdorff, so compact would imply closed).